# How to apply the same reflection rectangle to multiple items

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a set of transforms that I apply to make a fancy reflection for controls. I want to be able to apply the same stuff to other elements, but I don't know how to group it together, and apply it as a resource.

Can someone help me? Here is some code, this applies the transform to the first textbox. It looks a lot but is pretty simple, it is just a rectangle under a control, with a few transforms and other visual effects applied. What I want is to do the same with this rectangle but apply it to other controls (and so somehow parameterize the bindings.)

```
        <StackPanel Margin="40">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TitleDisp" FontSize="40" FontFamily="Verdana" Opacity="0.8" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Sample Title</TextBlock>
            <Rectangle Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=TitleDisp}" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=TitleDisp}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=TitleDisp}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.75"/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="10" AngleY="8"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="30" Y="-10"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#77000000"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <Rectangle.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect/>
                </Rectangle.Effect>
            </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Adorners` are what you are looking for here. They render on top of the controls in their own layer, and you can adorn any UIElement you wish, in your case you would be adorning the textbox with the rectangle that has those properties defined. The MSDN article on Adorners is a good start and it is a pretty easy read.

Comment: I'm confused, I don't see how the style can be applied. Are you suggesting I have a rectangle following each element with this style? If so I don't see how it can be bound to a different element. If the style can be applied to the text box, I don't understand how the rectangle can be created. Sorry, Newbie here.

Comment: @JessicaBoxer i see what you are saying, I think `Adorners` are what you are looking for here. They render on top of the controls in their own layer, and you can adorn any UIElement you wish, in your case you would be adorning the textbox with the rectangle that has those properties defined. The MSDN article on Adorners is a good start and it is a pretty easy read.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a good old user control ? the graphical object you want to be reflected would be the Content. So to use it you would do something like :

```
 <Reflect> <TextBlock Text="Wow so much sun" /> </Reflect>
```

Be carefull to bing the control width / height to the width+something and 2*Height of the Content (with Converters maybe)